# PHP: DOMDocument loadHTML returns error with nesty URL in href

Tags: php, domdocument

Recently I get an exception while I try to implement a special template engine.

Mine problem with DOMDocument load is in fact that I use some place holders in href and it will be replaced after with real values. I want to store that template and to use it each time when I need it, here is code sample

```
    $this->dom = new DOMDocument;
    $load_html = $this->dom->loadHTML($html);
```

And nesty part of HTML looks like

```
<a href="@_@web_site_address@_@">Visit our web site</a>
```

and exception is

```
Fatal error: DOMDocument::loadXML() [<a href='domdocument.loadxml'>domdocument.loadxml</a>]: EntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity
```

I was try to find a some way to skip that check but couldn't find anything.

Comment: are you actually using `@_@` as a placeholder? that might be setting it off.

Comment: I don't see why `@_@web_site_address@_@` should force an error, there must be wrong something else. You should look out for an ampersand, I'm pretty sure that you'll find the error there.

Comment: As I mentioned, I'm create a template system with place holders and if I put something which is not real URL I get exception...

Answer (score 3):

This causes no error in PHP 5.3. You must have some other HTML that is causing this. Normally you see this when you use an entity with no ; after it.

```
<a href="#">Foo &nbsp Bar</a>
```

That throws that same error for me. Look for some entity without a ; on it. Browsers will render that, but it is not correct.

Comment: Believe me that part causes error, for instance try to put <a href="#holder#">Foo &nbsp Bar</a> and to load it in HTML error will occurs. Looks like I have to change the parsing way for my entire system :(

Answer (score 3):

I found what was the problem. In my URL it was `&` sign, I was replace it with `&amp;` and now it works.